# Trouble applying the Soda Theme in Sublime Text 2

Tags: themes, sublimetext2, soda

I've installed the Soda Theme using the Package Control in Sublime Text 2, then activated it via Preferences -> Settings - User. However it doesn't get applied. Instead my theme now is Solarized, which is declared at the top of [my Preferences.sublime-settings file](https://gist.github.com/3142977) (line 3):

When I query the console for the theme, the output is correct:

```
>>> view.settings().get('theme')
u'Soda Light.sublime-theme'
```

This is correct, as well:

```
>>> view.settings().get('color_scheme')
u'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme'
```

Why do I see the Solarized theme and not Soda?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart Sublime Text 2? Double check you're following the instructions here: https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/.

Comment: Yes, I restarted ST2 several times following the Soda installation.

Comment: I had this problem - the problem was that I'd set the theme but not the color scheme.

Answer (score 7):

The Theme is not the text-editing screen's colours.

It is the chrome of the program, everything around the text editor; tab styles; etc.

If you check out [Soda on Github](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme#bonus-options) you can download and then use the same colour scheme as in the screenshots.

Comment: The direct link to the modified color schemes is http://buymeasoda.github.com/soda-theme/extras/colour-schemes.zip You need to unzip and put the tmtheme files in your Packages/User folder.

Comment: Where is the Packages/User folder?

Answer (score 3):

In case others are confused by the concept of color_scheme vs theme, this question was answered [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8288&p=34505).

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `,` after the first parameters set. It looks like this for me:

```
{
  "theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme",
  "ignored_packages":
  [
    "Vintage"
  ],
  "default_encoding": "UTF-8"
}
```